# Хочется(,) только(,) чтобы он вернулся

Tags: пунктуация

ПОдскажите, будьте добры, где должна быть запятая: Хочется(,) только(,) чтобы он вернулся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Хочется только, чтобы он вернулся.***

Это СПП с придаточным **изъяснительным**, частица ***только*** относится к глаголу. Смысл такой: Хочется лишь одного: чтобы он вернулся.

Пример:

Когда ты говоришь «буду, буду», значит, тебе **хочется только, чтобы** я от тебя отстала. [Леонид Юзефович. Костюм Арлекина (2001)]

Частица ***только*** может относится к придаточному цели, например:

Он понёс какую-то несусветную чушь, **только чтобы** она засмеялась. [И. Грекова.  (1967)]

Вроде обращаюсь к тебе, Танечка, но временами забываю и пишу что в голову приходит, **только чтобы** не растворилось. [Людмила Улицкая. , 2000]

Comment: откатил свои непреднамеренніе  изменения.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от смысла: смотря к чему относится "только"

Cравните:
**Только хочется, чтобы он вернулся побыстрее*** - возражение предыдыщего.
и
**Хочется, только чтобы он вернулся, ничего больше.***